# How to disable browser back button on home page in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we disable browser back button on home page if session is active.Same like Facebook site functionality??

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        function disableBack() { window.history.forward() }

        window.onload = disableBack();
        window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
    });
```

**[Read this document](http://www.encodedna.com/2014/07/restrict-or-disable-browser-back-button-using-javascript.htm)**